# Sign AWS S3 link (including versioning) in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sign, pre-signed-url

I've the folowing code that signs a URL to an object inside an S3 Bucket

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Now, if the Bucket has versioning enabled, how can I sign a specific version of the object link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`withVersionId(String)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#withVersionId-java.lang.String-):

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .withExpiration(expiration)
                .withVersionId("yourVesionId");
```

> Sets the version ID of the object, only present if versioning has been enabled for the bucket.

Comment: Using SDK 1.11.98, that version doesn't have .withVersionId() method. I'll upgrade. Thank you